# curl: keep cookies while being redirected

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I use this code (originally found [login into webpage with php with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224530/login-into-webpage-with-php-with-curl)) to first grab the csrf token, create cookie, and than use that csrf token and cookie in a subsequent post request. It doesn't work(deduced from how the final webpage looks) and I think it's because the FOLLOWLOCATION is set to true. It must be set to true, because there are some redirections going on, but redirections also bring the consequence of "misplacing" cookies. The question is..how to keep cookies while being redirected as a response from server.

```
 $cookie = 'cookies2.txt';

# Initialize a cURL session.
$ch = curl_init('https://example.com/login');

# Set the cURL options.
$options = [
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $useragent,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER=>1

];

# Set the options
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

# Execute
$html = curl_exec($ch);

$request = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
echo "1.Request sent: $request<br>";

$headerSizeFirst = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headersFirst = substr($html, 0, $headerSizeFirst);
echo "1.Request recieved: $headersFirst";

$dom = pQuery::parseStr($html);
$csrfToken = $dom->query('[name="csrf"]')->val();

 $postData = [
    'csrf'       => $csrfToken,
     'username'       => $email,
     'password'      => $password
             ...........

 ];


 # Convert the post data array to URL encoded string
 $postDataStr = http_build_query($postData);

 $options[CURLOPT_POST] = 1;
 $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postDataStr;
 $options[CURLOPT_HEADER]=1;
 $options[CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR]=$cookie;

 $options[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = true;
 $options[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
 $options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $useragent;
 $options[CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT] => true,



 curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

 # Execute
 $response = curl_exec($ch);

$request = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
echo "2. Request sent: $request<br>";

$headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = substr($response, 0, $headerSize);
echo "2. Request recieved: $headers<br>";
echo $response;
```

/////// HEADER OUT AND IN DATA

```
1.Request sent: GET /login HTTP/1.1 Host: example.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 Accept: */* 

1.Request recieved: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Accept-Ranges: bytes Age: 0 Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 13:34:02 GMT Server: nginx Set-Cookie: ____ri=4485; expires=Thu, 17-Mar-16 01:34:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dk7n4kcrigi54q081tr1evd5a2; path=/; domain=.example.com Set-Cookie: ts1=11e2bb0a86bfb9669c361cc407e1e3b3decefcce; expires=Fri, 06-Feb-2026 13:34:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com Set-Cookie: session=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%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 19-Feb-2016 13:34:02 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; httponly Vary: Accept-Encoding Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding X-Cache: Miss X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Content-Length: 51381 Connection: keep-alive 

2. Request sent: GET /inx/aeGDrYQ HTTP/1.1 Host: example.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 Accept: */* Cookie: PHPSESSID=t762fd0nbi1bp3hrgb9sgc3k20; ____ri=4485; safemode=1; session=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%3D; toastMsg=2; ts1=11e2bb0a86bfb9669c361cc407e1e3b3decefcce 


2. Request recieved: HTTP/1.1 302 Found Accept-Ranges: bytes Age: 0 Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 13:34:04 GMT location: http://example.com/inx/aeGDrYQ Server: nginx Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=thrn81mu7584dvp2ek9tpde8f4; expires=Thu, 09-Feb-2017 13:34:03 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=t762fd0nbi1bp3hrgb9sgc3k20; expires=Thu, 09-Feb-2017 13:34:03 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com Set-Cookie: session=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%3D; expires=Fri, 19-Feb-2016 13:34:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; httponly Set-Cookie: toastMsg=2; expires=Fri, 08-Feb-2019 13:34:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com Set-Cookie: unverified=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; httponly Set-Cookie: safemode=1; expires=Fri, 19-Feb-2016 13:34:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com Set-Cookie: cacheableGrace=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; httponly X-Cache: Miss X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive HTTP/1.1 200 OK Age: 0 Cache-Control: max-age=0, public, s-maxage=60 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 13:34:05 GMT Server: nginx Vary: Accept-Encoding Vary: Accept-Encoding X-Cache: Miss X-Cacheable: Yes X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN transfer-encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 1):

`CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` set to true means you tell libcurl to treat this as a *new* (cookie) session and it will discard all session cookies at start of a request. You should probably not set that without being really sure that's what you need as it will flush all cookies without a specific expiry date/time.

Otherwise, when the cookie engine has been activated in libcurl it will keep the cookies associated with the handle and reuse them in subsequent requests done with that same handle.

Comment: yes, I want to start fresh each time the code starts, but keep the cookies generated in first request  and use it in the second. This is an excerpt from the book I am reading: "Also, you’ll need to set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to false in order to prevent cURL from processing redirections automatically. Not doing this would cause any cookies set by requests resulting in redirections to be lost"

Comment: That book is wrong (and I would urge you to file a bug on it). libcurl does cookies equally good with or without redirects and it sends and uses cookies in all subsequent requests for which the cookies it has received matches (according to the cookie spec of course).

Comment: It's from 2010. maybe things were different back than. is there any way to debug why curl things don't work? The post has right address, tokens are the right, not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: No, it wasn't different back then. How do you even tell that the cookies are your problem? Check which cookies curl receives and sends in subsequent requests.

Comment: I extracted header out and header data. I added code and data to the original question. Cookies seem to be fine. To my surprise, the second request gets treated as GET request, although it should be POST. Could this be the error?

Comment: Yes that might be the problem, sure. What to do after a redirected POST is controlled by the response code (30x) but you can also control what curl does, with the CURLOPT_POSTREDIR option.

Comment: This is the first time I hear of POSTREDIR. To what should I set POSTREDIR?

Comment: We're now way off the original question and I'll stop here. You should read up on the documentation and/or update your question or post a new question.